# Replace sequence of characters in java

Tags: java

I am parsing a poorly structured rss feed, and some of the data that is being returned has `<p>at` in it. How can I replace all instance of `<p>at` with an empty space, using java?

I'm familiar with the `.replace` method for the String class, but I'm not sure how the regex expression would look. I tried `inputString.replace("<p>at", "")` but that didn't work.

Comment: Please show an SSCCE. The `replace()` doesn't use regex (and should thus just work). `replaceAll()` is the one which uses regex (which you should thus not use).

Comment: I meant replaceAll(). replace() woulnd't work because it takes a single character to replace.

Comment: Wow, are you *still* on Java 1.4 or older? Since Java 1.5 (released end of 2004), there are two `replace()` methods, one taking `char` and other taking `CharSequence` (and thus also `String`). In any way, this "typo" is precisely one of the reasons why you should show an SSCCE. So that we can in essence just copy'n'paste'n'run without changes to see your problem ourselves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
inputString = inputString.replace("<p>at", "");
```

Be aware that the [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method does *not* modify the `String` in-place (as is the case with **all** methods in the `String` class, because it's immutable), instead it returns a new `String` with the modifications - and you need to save the returned string somewhere.

Also, the above version of `replace()` doesn't receive a regular expression as an argument, just the string to be replaced and its replacement.

Comment: +1 The crucial point here is that Strings are ***immutable***.  It is impossible (well, unless you go to great lengths to fool the compiler) to change the value of a string.  All methods that "change" a string will return a _new_ string containing the modified value.

Comment: @JimGarrison spot-on!. I added that piece of information in my answer

Comment: @user1154644 if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputString.replace("<p>at", "") // this will replace all match's with second parameter charsequence
inputString.replaceAll("<p>at", "") //  Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
```

you can use anyone.

```
String newInputString = inputString.replaceAll("<p>at", "");
```

thanks

Comment: You're wrong. Read the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html